# Converting alt text to lowercase in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an image and I am trying to convert its alt text to lower case using jQuery:

I am using the following code:

```
var altattr = $('img').filter(function(){
            return $(this).attr('alt').toLowerCase().indexOf('alt') > -1;
            });
```

Comment: please add in the description the problem you are facing with your current code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a function as second parameter to the `.attr()` method. This function retrieves two arguments, the index and the value. Try with:

```
$('img').attr('alt', function(){
    return arguments[1].toLowerCase();
});
```

As @AlexeiLevenkov commented, for a better comprehension, see this example:

```
$('img').attr('alt', function(index, value){
    return value.toLowerCase();
});
```

Check out http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function

Comment: Looks very different from what OP's sample does (also likely what is needed). Side note: I think for most people using `...function(index, value){ return value.toLowerCase();} ...` would be more readable than `arguments[1]`.

Comment: Yes, well, you are right. I have the habit of use `arguments[1]` if I don't need to use the first argument. It's just for avoid declaring unused variables.